# Don't show picture miniature if i click like button and picture share miniature in my fan page, private profil etc

Tags: facebook-like

Hi I have problem with view share and like button in my page. If i click like button on my page for example this picture http://www.debuton.com/obrazek.php?206 i have this window http://scr.hu/8qi/a8n7g and I doens't have picture miniature and this is view with my profile when i click the like button. Same here with share button they doesn't view picture miniature only link :/ please help me

I will be grateful

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.debuton.com%2Fobrazek.php%3F206

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you are using? Make sure you have `data-show-faces="true"` so you can see the faces of users who have liked the page. If the user's privacy settings are strong, you won't seen an image no matter what settings you change.